# php функция mail

Tags: php, email

Осваиваю php, работаю на localhost (Denver)
Пытаюсь отправить почту:

```
// the message
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
mail("92431@mail.ru","My subject",$msg);
$message = "email is sent 2";
```

Ошибку не выдаёт, но почта пуста, может ли это быть связанно с тем, что работаю на localhost, и как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: `mail` что возвращает?

Answer (score 1):

При работе с Denwer все "отправленные" e-mail накапливаются в папке Webservers\tmp!sendmail в формате .eml, который можно открыть в любой почтовой программе.
Посмотреть все письма также можно в браузере по адресу http://localhost/Tests/sendmail/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. Денвер предназначен прежде всего для отладки, использование «реального» sendmail в нем вряд ли оправдано. Именно по этой причине базовый пакет содержит «отладочную заглушку» для sendmail, которая складывает письма, приходящие от скриптов на Perl и PHP, в файл /tmp/!sendmail.txt.

В большинстве случаев этого должно быть достаточно, однако, если вам все же потребуется настоящий сервер, можно порекомендовать, например, вот этот: http://courierms.narod.ru

Источник: http://www.denwer.ru/faq/other.html#h30-27

Answer (score 0):

Письмо отправляется не на почту,они сохраняются в папке /tmp/.
Копайте в сторону SMTP,удачи)